# Replacing elements with lxml.html

Tags: python, lxml

I'm fairly new to lxml and HTML Parsers as a whole.
I was wondering if there is a way to replace an element within a tree with another element...

For example I have:

```
body = """<code> def function(arg): print arg </code> Blah blah blah <code> int main() { return 0; } </code> """

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(body)
codeblocks = doc.cssselect('code')

for block in codeblocks:
  lexer = guess_lexer(block.text_content())
  hilited = highlight(block.text_content(), lexer, HtmlFormatter())
  doc.replace(block, hilited)
```

I want to do something along those lines, but this results in a "TypeError" because "hilited" isn't an lxml.etree._Element.

Is this feasible?

Regards,

Comment: I've been searching around and I noticed BeautifulSoup has this exact functionality via replaceWith, is there something similar to -this- in lxml? (If not that's alright however, I'm still intrested)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding lxml,

In `doc.replace(block, hilited)`

**block** is the lxml's Element object, **hilited** is string, you cannot replace that.

There is 2 ways to do that

```
block.text=hilited
```

or

```
body=body.replace(block.text,hilited)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to python HTML parsers, you might try out [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), a html/xml parser, which lets you [modify the parse tree easily](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Modifying%20the%20Parse%20Tree).

Comment: I've just looked at BeautifulSoup, it seems like it might be a better fit then lxml.html for my uses. Thanks for the suggestion!