# Replace element text

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812764/replacing-elements-with-lxml-html) that in order to replace an element text, I would just have to use `replace`. For some reason in my code it throws this error:

```
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Here is the code:

```
from lxml import etree

old = 'Hello'
new = 'bye'

xml.replace(currentText, newText)
```

The code above is simplified. What I want is to replace one tag text with another text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no.
_ElementTree.replace actualy replaces subelement with element passed as second argument.
All you need to  is:

```
xml.text = new_text
```

By the way, http://lxml.de can be wery useful, it have a lot of information and code examples for such cases.